# Angular 6 restore passed parameter to its original values after close ngbModal

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I have a table with objects with edit and delete buttons, so when I pass a paremeter(object in row) from parentComponent to an "edit" modal (using ngbModal) and then change some values but then I regret and I close it with the X in the header of the modal the table keeps the last value changed, so how can I restore the parameter to its original value?

This is my parentComponent.ts function to open modal and pass paremeter:

```
//receives the element from row and pass it to modal
openModalEdit(element){
    const modalRefCity = this.modalService.open(ModalEditComponent);
    modalRefCity.componentInstance.horario = element;

    modalRefCity.componentInstance.horarioevent.subscribe(($e) => {
        this.editHorario($e);
        this.modalService.dismissAll();
        console.log($e);
    })
}
```

This works fine, the modal is open and the value is passed for edit.

This is my ModalEditComponent:

```
export class ModalEditComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() horario;
    @Output() horarioevent = new EventEmitter<string>();

     constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

    updateHorario(){

     this.horarioevent.emit(this.horario);
    }
```

This is my modal-edit.component.html

```
<div class="modal-header">

 <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  ...
```

So the when I change the values of horario (parameter passed from parent) and then save the new values it works perfectly, (edit function works fine).

The problem is when I open the modal, then change some values of horario and then regret, so close the modal using the X button in the modal header, the modal gets closed but the objects show its values with the last changes I made (I know that this are only in my view not in my db).

How can I reset the parameter to its original values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to utilize Spread syntax to pass a copy of data from parent component to the child

```
modalRefCity.componentInstance.horario = {...element};
```

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)